# apt-get upgrade not finding packages

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, apt

When I ssh into my server I get this banner:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-45-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage


11 packages can be updated.
8 updates are security updates.
```

But when I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 ubuntu-desktop
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 4 not to upgrade.
```

What's going on here, why do the ssh login and apt-get disagree?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't `sudo apt-get update` first.

Always `update` before `upgrade`!